# CSS - Seletor "::"

Tags: css, css3

Em estudos sobre os seletores CSS, temos visto o seletor `::` em alguns momentos. 
Porém não encontrei referência específica sobre este keyword `::` isolado. Ou seja, eu só vi ele sendo aplicado em seletores principalmente relacionado à pseudo-elementos.

> **Exemplo:** `T::first-letter`

Porém não entendi o que ele significa, e também não entendi se existe algum padrão que identifique uma possibilidade de uso dele.

Podem ajudar a levantar a referência sobre isto?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isso chama-se [`pseudo-elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elementos) e [estão disponíveis na maior parte dos browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-selection).

Os seletores de CSS normalmente referem-se a elementos do DOM, este pseudo seletor `::` refere-se a elementos que não estão diferênciados no DOM. Pode ser a primeira letra por exemplo:

```css
::first-letter {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Algum texto!</p>
```

ou a primeira linha:

```css
::first-line {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Algum texto!<br>e a continuação</p>
```

ou acrescentando texto que não existe no DOM:

```css
p::before {
  content: 'Nota: ';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Algum texto!</p>
```

[A lista é](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elementos):

```
::after
::before
::first-letter
::first-line
::selection
::backdrop 
::placeholder 
::marker 
::spelling-error 
::grammar-error
```

Comment: Sergio, e estes se aplicam somente no <p> ou em outras tags também?

Comment: @BrunoHeringer não é especifico do `<p>`, funciona com outras tags também.