# O que significa sinal de >, :: , +, e & em css?

Tags: css

Estou começando meu estágio e não sei o siginificado dos seguintes atibutos.

> Sinal de > (maior)

Porque é usado `.classe-a > classe-b{}`

> Dois pontos duplo

```
 .classe-a::.classe-b{}
```

> Sinal de + (mais)

```
.classe-a + classe-b
```

> Sinal de &

```
&.classe-a{}
```

Eu vou dar manutenção nesse `CSS` mas antes preciso saber o que são esses sinais?

Comment: Duplicata de [**CSS - Seletor “::”**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201503/3635) e [**Qual a diferença entre os seletores “element element” e “element>element”?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2256/3635) e [**O que significa o sinal de + no CSS?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91175/3635)

Comment: **Nota:** O uso do seletor `::` na sua pergunta esta errado, aquilo não existe `::` é para pseudo-elementos nativos - **Nota 2:** O seletor `&` não existe em CSS, provavelmente ele é do [**Sass**](http://sass-lang.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Sinal de maior `>`:** significa filho-direto do elemento. Seleciona todos os filhos-diretos do elemento.

Exemplo: `div > span`

```
<div>
  <span> <!-- filho direto da div -->
     DvD
     <p>DvD</p> <!-- não é filho direto da div -->
  </span>
</div>
```

- **Dois pontos `::`:** significa pseudo-elemento (um elemento-filho).

Exemplo: `div::first-letter`

Seleciona a primeira letra dentro da div (no caso abaixo, o "d").

```
<div>
   <span>
      dvd
   </span>
</div>
```

> Seu exemplo `.classe-a::.classe-b{}` está incorreto. Uma classe não
>   pode ser um pseudo-elemento.

Documentação de pseudo-elementos no [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elementos).

- **- Sinal de `+`:** seleciona o elemento imediatamente após.

Exemplo: `div + p`

```
<div>
   dvd
</div>
<p>dvd</p> <!-- este é selecionado, pois está após a div -->
<p>dvd</p> <!-- este não é selecionado -->
```

- **Sinal `&`:** este sinal não existe no CSS. Ele é usado no [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html), uma linguagem para compilar códigos CSS.

Comment: A pergunta já esta marcada como dup, já existem respostas que respondem e você ainda insisti em fazer dup - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252589/o-que-significa-sinal-de-e-em-css#comment518219_252589 - Por favor favoreça as respostas existentes.