# Remoção de elemento com Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Remover um elemento usando `Jquery` é a coisa mais simples e objetiva que existe, primeiro você captura o elemento e depois o remove:

```
$('#elemento').remove();
```

Cheguei em uma situação em que preciso remover o elemento apenas com javascript puro, mas pelo que entendi, é necessário capturar o nó do elemento pai para depois remover o elemento alvo:

```
var elemento = document.getElementById("elemento");
elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento);
```

Não consigo entender o motivo de fazer isso, nem mesmo entender como esse código está funcionando.

1- Como esse código funciona?

2 - Qual o motivo do `javascript` precisar ir para o nó pai primeiro para depois remover o elemento?

3 - porque com o `jquery` é tão simples realizar a remoção?

Comment: **1.** O código seleciona o elemento pai, após isso, na função *removeChild*, ele percorre todos os elementos filhos até encontrar o elemento passado via parâmetro, quando o código encontra ele utiliza a função *remove*. 

**2.** Não é o *JavaScript* (de modo geral) que precisa ir para o nó pai, é a função que exige. Você pode usar `element.remove()`. 

**3.** Porque o *jQuery* é uma biblioteca composta por vários códigos para que deixe o *script* mais fácil, apesar se mais lento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como o próprio nome do método sugere, `removeChild()` (*remover filho*), ele precisa de um elemento pai para buscar um filho, e precisa ser um **[filho direto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252592/8063)**, caso contrário retorna em erro.

Mas você pode remover o elemento diretamente sem precisar de pai usando o método `remove()`:

```
document.getElementById("id-do-elemento").remove();
```

Ou `outerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("id-do-elemento").outerHTML = '';
```

> Segundo o **[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=remove())**, o `.remove()` não é compatível com o Internet Explorer.

### jQuery

O jQuery é apenas uma biblioteca que visa simplificar o uso do JavaScript. Na maioria dos casos, uma simples linha de código em jQuery faz o que você faria com algumas linhas em JavaScript puro, mas essa facilidade tem um preço: é mais lento por ser um intermediário e você precisa carregar a biblioteca na página.