# Alguém me explica esse código, por favor? (.clearfix::after) - CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alguém me explica essa parte do código?

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  border: 3px solid #4CAF50;
  padding: 5px;
}

.img1 {
  float: right;
}

.img2 {
  float: right;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Without Clearfix</h2>

<p>This image is floated to the right. It is also taller than the element containing it, so it overflows outside of its container:</p>

<div>
  <img class="img1" src="pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="170" height="170">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet...
</div>

<h2 style="clear:right">With New Modern Clearfix</h2>
<p>Add the clearfix hack to the containing element, to fix this problem:</p>

<div class="clearfix">
  <img class="img2" src="pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="170" height="170">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet...
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Não consegui entender.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91528/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-pseudo-classe-dois-pontos-e-pseudo-elemento-duplo-dois-pont

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201503/css-seletor/201505#201505

Comment: Esse código é comumente utilizado pra resolver problemas de `clearfix`, que acontecem quando um elemento contém elementos flutuantes e não tem altura definida, fazendo com que o conteúdo subsequente não apareça corretamente na página. A classe ".clearfix" é adicionada ao elemento que contém os elementos flutuantes para forçar o seu contêiner a expandir e englobar todo o conteúdo, evitando assim que os elementos flutuantes escapem e afetem outros elementos da página.

Comment: `clear:both` pode ser aplicado em um elemento normal também e esse ser usado para "encerrar" a flutuação de elementos com float que vieram antes, o pseudo elemento ::after ali só é usado para criar automaticamente via CSS um elemento que encerra a flutuação, sem precisar que você adicione um elemento manualmente. O float faz com que outros elementos sejam afetados, com o clear você encerra isso, a documentação da MDN já tem as respostas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after